# Installing CUDA 4.0 over 3.2

Tags: drivers, installation, cuda

I am currently using CUDA 3.2 and would like to try out CUDA 4.0. Do I simply install CUDA 4.0 over 3.2? Will I need to remove anything, e.g. drivers etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're no longer interested in this question, but might be someone else will look for an answer:

No, it's not necessary to remove anything explicitly, the installer will offer to uninstall previous version automatically at the very beginning. You can, however, install newer version of CUDA into another directory without removing previous one, thus having two (or more) different versions of CUDA Toolkit (and switch between them with, for example, `update-alternatives` if you use linux).

You must however update your video driver to the version shipped with latest toolkit (or newer), or you would get runtime errors. Again, it's not necessary to explicitly uninstall previous driver.